# How to update User's name every time someone new logs into website and have a logout button using html and python

Tags: html, pythonanywhere

I wanted to change my html code so that everytime someone logs in, it changes the username in the menu section. Here is my class of User and my html code that consists of the section in which I want the username to update.

HTML Code:

```
<!-- Sidebar/menu -->
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-white w3-animate-left" style="z-index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidebar"><br>
  <div class="w3-container w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col s4">
      <img src="/w3images/avatar2.png" class="w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:46px">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s8 w3-bar">
      <span>Welcome, <strong>username.users</strong></span><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="w3-container">``
```

Python Code:

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))


    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)


    def get_id(self):
        return self.username``
```

I do also have the html code in which logs the user into the main website but that is working fine. I am working on pythonanywhere. I have always assigned certain users access because I do not yet know how to let anyone sign up and I am unsure if that is messing up something in my code.

Comment: read up on how to do django templating?

Comment: I am using flask not Django

Comment: Flask templating is pretty similar.  Perhaps it would be worth going through a tutorial covering it?  This one on the PythonAnywhere blog covers templates, and you could create a throwaway account on the site to go through it: https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/

Comment: But a shorter answer -- you'll need to specify in the template that the username is something you want to be replaced with the actual username by using something like `{{user.username}}`, and then pass `user` into `render_template`